Visualize SceneGraphCollisionChecker
Is there a way to visualize the bodies of a SceneGraphCollisionChecker? I can't figure out how to connect it to Meshcat since you need a robot builder to use AddDefaultVisualization.
The SceneGraphCollisionChecker is telling me there are collisions between objects but I can't figure out why. Being able to visualize it would help a lot.

A little more detail would help. If you want to visualize the SceneGraph collision geometry (which is used by the SceneGraphCollisionChecker), then Drake's ModelVisualizer (e.g. in the authoring_multibody_plant tutorial) is the tool for that. With a few clicks in Meshcat, you can turn off the visual geometry and display the collision geometry instead.
If you're using extra features from SceneGraphCollisionChecker, like the collision padding, then I guess it's true that we don't actually offer an out-of-the-box visualizer for that.
